# Reorder all rows in a SQLite table with a custom `order_index` column

Tags: arrays, sqlite, sorting

I have a SQLite table `persons`:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+
| id        | name     | order_index |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
| (primary) |          | (unique)    |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
| 0         | Paul     | 1           |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
| 1         | Sammy    | 2           |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
| 2         | Caren    | 0           |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
| 3         | Muhammed | 3           |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
```

I have to keep track of the order using a custom column `order_index`. The `order_index` column has to start at `0`.

Let's say I want to move `Muhammed` to position `1`. This requires me to update the `order_index` of `Sammy` and `Paul` too. The `order_index` of `Caren` doesn't need to change, since `1 > 0`.

Is it possible to achieve this using SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requirement is tricky because it involves multiple updates which depend on each other and the order of these updates is not guaranteed.

First update all the other rows that must be updated except the row of the person that you want to move:

```
with cte as (
  select name, order_index current_index, ? new_index
  from persons 
  where name = 'Muhammed'
) 
update persons
set order_index = order_index + 
  case 
    when (select current_index from cte) > (select new_index from cte) then 1 
    else -1 
  end
where name <> (select name from cte) 
  and order_index between 
    min((select current_index from cte), (select new_index from cte))
    and
    max((select current_index from cte), (select new_index from cte));
```

Then update the row of the person that you want to move:

```
update persons
set order_index = ?                                        
where name = 'Muhammed';
```

Replace `?` placeholders in both queries with the new position.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/urL9FEnqqMSXnF1SWosYbT/10).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, because your entire data model might need to be changed, but I would handle this specific requirement with the following query:

```
UPDATE persons
SET order_index = (SELECT MIN(order_index) FROM persons) - 1
WHERE name = 'Muhammed';
```

That is, just bump Muhammed's position to one minus the current highest priority.  Then, your business logic should be to always serve the person with the smallest order index (which might even go negative).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution ([demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9zMXpiBXAmw8mr9NAWXCPb/0)) based on [Tim's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61615748/2906284) and [forpas's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61613527/2906284) suggestions:

```
# Move person from index 4 to index 2:

# Update target index.
update persons
set order_index = NULL                                        
where order_index = 4; # FROM

# Update indexes >= TO.
update persons
set order_index = order_index + 1                                        
where order_index >= 2; # TO

# Update indexes > FROM.
update persons
set order_index = order_index - 1                                        
where order_index > 4; # FROM

# Update target.
update persons
set order_index = 2 # TO                                     
where order_index IS NULL;

# Show results.
select id, name, order_index from persons ORDER BY order_index;
```

I think this solution is somewhat easier to grasp than forpas's suggestion. However, are there any reasons to use forpas's suggestion instead?

Comment: Do you consider this a solution? What will you do if you want to move Caren from 0 to 3? Will you write 4 new update queries? And what if there are 10 or 100 rows in the table?

Comment: Good points! I hadn't though of those situations. And I meant to refer to your (forpas's) solution. I'll accept it right away!